# How can I get today's date in a cell in dd/mm/yyyy format?

Tags: excel, vba, date, excel-2016, regional-settings

I want to put today's date (4 November 2018) into a cell in this (`dd/mm/yyyy`) format:

```
    04/11/2018
```

However every attempt so far leads to (`mm/dd/yyyy` format):

```
    11/04/2018
```

Original code is:

```
    Dim sToday As String
    sToday = Date
    Cells(nCurrentRow, nCurrentColumn) = sToday
```

What I have tried includes:

```
    Cells(nCurrentRow, nCurrentColumn).Value = sToday
```

and:

```
    Cells(nCurrentRow, nCurrentColumn).Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"
```

and:

```
    sToday = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
```

When I output the string in a message box, it always appears in the desired format: `04/11/2018`

Even when I post the date as a plain string in the correct format `04/11/2018` the format still changes!

Windows 10 regional settings are as I require  (UK date format).

The cell format is also set to `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Comment: Go to your Windows Regional Settings and tell me what is in the **Short Date** settings box.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: `dd/MM/yyyy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your algorithm is getting bollixed by VBA US-Centric date preferences.
No matter your windows short date regional setting, all you need do is insert the variable as a Date (not as a string).

When VBA converts today's date to a string, it is in the US Format.  Therefore numberformat in the destination cell will not have any affect on a string, nor will the VBA format function.  Both of those act on numbers/dates but not on strings, the way you are using it.

For example, try:

```
With Cells(1, 1)
    .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    .Value = Date
End With
```

or, using your variable assignments:

```
   Dim dToday As Date
dToday = Date

With Cells(nCurrentRow, nCurrentColumn)
    .Value = dToday
    .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub test()
Dim sToday As String
sToday = Date
sToday = Format(sToday, "dd mm yyyy")

MsgBox sToday
Cells(1, 1).Value = sToday
End Sub
```

I tried this, and I got the wished result.
The workaround is to save the date in a string and format the string.

Comment: Sorry, this did not work for me. Got the same result as before.

Comment: this worked with a sligh adjustment - had to first assign sToday = Date, and then do the transformation as dToday = Format(...). When I then inserted dToday into the field it showed the desired format.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get today's date in a cell in dd/mm/yyyy format?

Since your configuration is UK format:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>

Comment: Neat trick, but I'm looking for a macro answer. I tried recording this in a macro and got `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "11/4/2018"` :(